# Sencha CMD not started

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I downloaded Sencha Architect and Sencha CMD, but I can't run Secnha web server. I start it in my command line, then I see this:
[image]
Can anyone help?

Comment: That looks like the server started from your pic.  If you leave that command line open and go to your browser and navigate to http://localhost:1841, is the server responding?